# how to validate a oracle query is correct or not?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, oracle10g

Hi Tech Folks,
              I am developing a .net application in C# through which we will give a front end to the users where they will write a query and the result set is shown in a gridview table
So i just want to  know that how can i validate a oracle query/syntax from my end 
Kindly help me to get possible ways to validate this oracle query from my side

Answer (score 0):

> **A.** Parser

Build your own or use something that already exists: http://www.antlr3.org/download.html

> **B.** Relay

Send the command to an Oracle database and return the DB response to the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to rework? All is done by the Database server you are using. Just Add a Try ... Catch.. Portion, get the exception on execution of given query and show it to your user.
[See the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx)